# FHIR Organization with webservice urls

Tags: web-services, hl7-fhir

Is there an existing use case or resource that can be used to act as a webservice registry/directory in HL7 FHIR?

I'm wondering if I have to have an Other resource that holds values for the web service endpoints that I want to share for each Organization resource (which would be extended to have this Other Endpoint resource)

For example:
An organization can support XDR/XDS.b/NwHIN services and I want to include the endpoints for each service type, such as:

```
"endpoint": [
  { 
    "name": "NwHIN Document Submission",
    "url": "https//nwhinDSendpoint"
  },
  { 
    "name": "XDSB Provide and Register Document Set-B",
    "url": "https//xdsbProvideAndRegister"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do these as extensions in the Organization resource:

```
 {
  "resourceType" : "Organization",
   ...
   "extension" : [{ 
     "url" : "http://joySmoth.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/nwhinDSendpoint",
     "valueUri" : "https//nwhinDSendpoint"
    }]
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Grahame.  Is there any consideration for a resource or extension to Organization for accounting for webservice/api descriptions for communications?  Trying to see if this could be used for a combination of an HPD/UDDI registry.  Thanks again.

Comment: FWIW, this is also how SMART publishes OAuth2 endpoints; as extension on _ConformanceStatement_ at `/metadata`, see here (slightly out of date): http://docs.smarthealthit.org/authorization/conformance-statement/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Grahame's answer above.
With these registries or endpoints there is often an Identifier that is critical too so would actually encourage the use of this extension being on a specific Identifier that is relevant to this.

The other consideration is that this may be more than just organizational, and could be more finely tuned down at the HealthcareService level (if you're using these) or even at the Practitioner.

Another complexity you may wish to consider are the security implications and requirements of this registry. Public Key management for digital certificates may be required if using this approach, maybe even indicating/including the supported root certs. (or public keys for encrypting content before submission)